# How to make docker volume update automatically?

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile with the following commands. Nothing fancy. (for context: made from [this tutorial](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/))

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
ADD . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I run a build, it all works.

```
local:~/projects/tap/ws$ docker build -t test-img .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 13.82 kB
Step 1/8 : FROM node:boron
 ---> 3f3928767182
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ba120374422
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c6f6cccd7833
Step 4/8 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2c7f185c3e3f
Step 5/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0197f3d8777b
Step 6/8 : ADD . /usr/src/app
 ---> 6a2df3e80f66
Removing intermediate container 93a56a2721e8
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in ff21ca7efd15
 ---> 53cda9fd451f
Removing intermediate container ff21ca7efd15
Step 8/8 : CMD npm start
 ---> Running in 293d99bb9ca3
 ---> b8e026d96ba7
Removing intermediate container 293d99bb9ca3
Successfully built b8e026d96ba7
```

And then it boots up just fine.

```
local:~/projects/tap/ws$ docker run -p 49160:8080 -d -v /Users/amflare/projects/tap/ws/test:/user/src/app/test --name test test-img
22ce30a882be992cd245ef3bcb15a945b40c4507d2f56a366b410c12bbe9d801
```

But the mounted volume `/usr/src/app/test` will not update when I make changes in the host directory. From what I can tell from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/), it should just *work*. The mount exists (see below), and everything built and ran correctly. So I am at a loss. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Since this is the most simple of docker containers, I hope that someone has encountered, and solved this problem before.

```
local:~/projects/tap/ws$ docker inspect test

...

Mounts": [
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/Users/amflare/projects/tap/ws/test",
    "Destination": "/user/src/app/test",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  }
],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did just a typo here `/user/src/app/test`. It should be `/usr`, not `/user`. So fix your `docker run -v....`.

I can see that it is not a typo only in Stack Overflow due to you showed this:

```
Mounts": [
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/Users/amflare/projects/tap/ws/test",
    "Destination": "/user/src/app/test",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  }
],
```